# Recyclerview java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundException

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

When I scroll down too fast and click on whatever item I land on I get this following error then the app crashes: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{440a7260 position=15 id=-1, oldPos=14, pLpos:14 scrap tmpDetached no parent} I have read that it's a (known) bug in the recyclerview. Does someone have a way to bypass it? Maybe restrict scroll to let all the JSON data to load properly in recyclerview

I use the following method to send my JSON request

```
private void sendJsonRequest(){
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlUpcoming, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            gamesList.addAll(parseJsonResponse(response));
            adapterUpcoming.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapterUpcoming.setData(gamesList);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //error getting data
        }
    });

    //add the request
    mRequestQueue.add(request);
}
```

The parseJsonResponse returns an array list, this is where the magic happens(fetching the data from the api)

```
 private ArrayList<Game> parseJsonResponse(JSONObject response) {
    final ArrayList<Game> games = new ArrayList<>();
    //{fetching data with volley} code omitted
    return games;
}
```

OnCreateView

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upcoming, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.upcomingGamesList);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    adapterUpcoming = new AdapterUpcoming(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterUpcoming);
    urlUpcoming = MyApplication.getUrl(); //the url from which I'm fetching my data 
    sendJsonRequest();
    return view;
```

Error (The error is the same but values different):

```
E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{52ea27c0 position=5 id=-1, oldPos=4, pLpos:4 scrap tmpDetached no parent}
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:3229)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3359)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3340)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1810)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1306)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1269)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:523)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:1942)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2237)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1594)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:502)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, I think you should post your code.

Comment: "I'll post my code for context if you guys want" - no, you should post your code regardless if we want it or not... otherwise it's practically impossible to help you :)

Comment: @Adam, post stacktrace and some part of code, so i can assist you

Comment: And with the stacktrace make sure to include the "caused by" part as well as show us which line in your code triggered it.

Answer (score 0):

Please always post the code that you need help with. Also make sure that this code is concise and well commented. However an IndexOutOfBounds exception means that somewhere you are trying to look at a string or an array. And looking at A negative number or a number too high. But it says position 15 so it is going past the end of the array. Trying adding a check statement if(oldPosition+1

Comment: huh it seems like it still is giving an out of bounds error. It is still parsing the array incorrectly. Look for an off by one error somehwere on line 3229.